# How to use a column value as key to a dictionary in PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a small PySpark DataFrame `df`:

```
index    col1
0        1    
1        3
2        4
```

And a dictionary:

```
LOOKUP = {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 6}
```

I now want to add an extra column `col2` to `df`, equal to the `LOOKUP` values of `col1`.

My output should look like this:

```
index    col1 col2
0        1    5    
1        3    4
2        4    6
```

I tried using:

```
df = df.withColumn(col("col2"), LOOKUP[col("col1")])
```

But this gave me errors, as well as using `expr`.

How to achieve this in PySpark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `map` column that you create from the `lookup` dictionary:

```py
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

lookup = {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 6}
lookup_map = F.create_map(*[F.lit(x) for x in chain(*lookup.items())])

df1 = df.withColumn("col2", lookup_map[F.col("col1")])

df1.show()
#+-----+----+----+
#|index|col1|col2|
#+-----+----+----+
#|    0|   1|   5|
#|    1|   3|   4|
#|    2|   4|   6|
#+-----+----+----+
```

Another way would be to create a `lookup_df` from the dict then join with your dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You van use a `CASE WHEN` statement with python `f-strings` here with the `LOOKUP` dictionary:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
column = 'col1' #column to replace
e = f"""CASE {' '.join([f"WHEN {column}='{k}' THEN '{v}'" for k,v in LOOKUP.items()])} 
        ELSE NULL END"""
out = df.withColumn("col2",F.expr(e))
```

---

```
out.show()

+-----+----+----+
|index|col1|col2|
+-----+----+----+
|    0|   1|   5|
|    1|   3|   4|
|    2|   4|   6|
+-----+----+----+
```