# transform a spark dataframe based on the value of a column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have the dataframe below:

| s.id | s.first | s.last | s.age | d.first | d.last | d.age | UPDATED_FIELDS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | BBB | 10 | AAA__ | BBB | 10 | ["first"] |
| 2 | CCC | DDD | 20 | CCC__ | DDD | 21 | ["first", "age"] |

I want to transform it to the format below, so for each of the `UPDATED_FIELDS` in the first dataframe, I want to create a new row in my second dataframe.

| id | field | s_value | d_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first | AAA | AAA_ |
| 2 | first | CCC | CCC_ |
| 2 | age | 20 | 21 |

I feel like I need to create a new dataframe, but couldn't get it working

Comment: You can simply explode the column. `df.withColumn("field", explode("UPDATED_FIELDS"))`.

Comment: @Lamanus how do populate the value fields though?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't straightforward because after you explode `"UPDATED_FIELDS"` to create the `"field"` column, you have the following dataframe:

```
+----+-------+------+-----+-------+------+-----+--------------+-----+
|s.id|s.first|s.last|s.age|d.first|d.last|d.age|UPDATED_FIELDS|field|
+----+-------+------+-----+-------+------+-----+--------------+-----+
|   1|    AAA|   BBB|   10|  AAA__|   BBB|   10|       [first]|first|
|   2|    CCC|   DDD|   20|  CCC__|   DDD|   21|  [first, age]|first|
|   2|    CCC|   DDD|   20|  CCC__|   DDD|   21|  [first, age]|  age|
+----+-------+------+-----+-------+------+-----+--------------+-----+
```

The new columns `s_value` and `d_value` depend on using the literal from the exploded column `"field"` to tell us which column's value to use. It would be nice to do something like:

```
df.withColumn(
    "field", F.explode("UPDATED_FIELDS")
).withColumn(
    "s_value", F.col(f"s.{F.col('field')}")
)
```

... but this will result in an error because `{F.col('field')}` cannot be interpreted as a literal.

Update: based on [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70462865/how-to-use-a-column-value-as-key-to-a-dictionary-in-pyspark), you can in fact use a string literal as a column lookup. You will want to first make sure you can access `df['field']` so you need to perform the explode separately first, then use `F.coalesce(*F.when(...))` as a way of obtaining the value inside the column name that comes from the string inside `df['field']`:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    "field", F.explode("UPDATED_FIELDS")
)

## obtain list of all unique strings in "field"
base_cols = df.select(F.collect_set("field").alias("column")).first()["column"]

df.withColumn(
    "s_value",  F.coalesce(*[F.when(df['field'] == c, df[f"`s.{c}`"]) for c in base_cols])
).withColumn(
    "d_value",  F.coalesce(*[F.when(df['field'] == c, df[f"`d.{c}`"]) for c in base_cols])
).select(
    F.col("`s.id`").alias("id"),"field","s_value","d_value"
)

+---+-----+-------+-------+
| id|field|s_value|d_value|
+---+-----+-------+-------+
|  1|first|    AAA|  AAA__|
|  2|first|    CCC|  CCC__|
|  2|  age|     20|     21|
+---+-----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: my UPDATED_FIELDS is not fixed though, but I suppose this is a good start for me. Thanks.

Comment: @gherkin what is the expected output if `UPDATED_FIELDS` contains a literal that isn't one of `"first"`,`"age"`,`"last"`? or is this solution meant for a dataframe with more columns than shown?

Comment: an alternative solution would be to use a `udf` but this has the disadvantage of losing optimization

Comment: @dereck-o Updated field will always be from the list of columns, it's just I am not sure what columns will be there for the data I am processing. I used this three fields as an example just to explain what transformation I need to do

Comment: @gherkin updated with what is hopefully a better answer for your use case. we still need to know whether we are using `s.{col}` or `d.{col}` when we are looking up the column name from the `"field"` column