# How to use multiple columns as maps for nested dictionary to create a new dataframe column?

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, pyspark

I am trying to use 2 pyspark dataframe columns as an input to a nested dictionary to get the output as a new pyspark column. Also would want the solution to scale to a nested dictionary with 4-5 levels.

The dictionary is of the form:
dict_prob={"a":{"x1":"y1","x2:y2"},"b":{"m1":"n1","m2":"n2"}}

Input Columns are:

| index | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | x1 |
| 1 | a | x2 |
| 2 | b | m2 |

Output Column Needed

| col3 |
| --- |
| y1 |
| y2 |
| n2 |

I tried the below links but these seem to work for a single dictionary and not for a nested dictionary.
[PySpark create new column with mapping from a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980704/pyspark-create-new-column-with-mapping-from-a-dict)
[How to use a column value as key to a dictionary in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70462865/how-to-use-a-column-value-as-key-to-a-dictionary-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given example, you can use a simple [`udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html) :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

two_lvls = udf(lambda l1, l2: dict_prob[l1][l2])

df = df.withColumn("col3", two_lvls(df.col1, df.col2))
```

Output :

```
df.show()

+-----+----+----+----+
|index|col1|col2|col3|
+-----+----+----+----+
|    0|   a|  x1|  y1|
|    1|   a|  x2|  y2|
|    2|   b|  m2|  n2|
+-----+----+----+----+
```